# Show that T is diagonalizable if nullity$(T) + m = n.$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

$V$ is a vector space of dimension $n > 0$, let $T:  V \to V$ be a linear operator and $ { 0, \lambda _{1}, ..., \lambda_{m} } $ be a set of the distinct eigenvalues of T . Show that T is diagonalizable if nullity$(T) + m = n$.

My Try:I think we can directly claim that $T$ is diagonalizable since it splits into distinct linear factor.Thank you

Comment: First, I believe it should be $\lambda_m$ instead of $\lambda_n$. Secondly, when you say 'it splits into distinct linear factors', what do you mean by 'it'?

Comment: Your proof should just show the existence of $n$ linear independent eigenvectors. This is basically a trivial consequence of the assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a linear map (or a matrix...) is diagonalizable iff for each and every eigenvalue, it algebraic and geometric multiplicities are equal, and this is the same as saying that the sum of all the geometric multiplicities of all the eigenvalues equals the space's dimension, i.e. $\;n\;$

For the eigenvalue zero: its geometric multiplicity equals the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace, which of course is $\;\ker T\;$ : $\;\dim\ker T=\text{null.}\,T\;$ , but then we get the above mentioned condition for diagonability as we're givenb

$$\overbrace{null.\,T+m}^{\text{sum of geom. mult.}}=n$$

Comment: The fact that the $\lambda_i$ have multiplicitly $1$ is not an explicit assumption, it is a consequence of the assumptions, which one has to derive. So the start of the proof 'We don't worry about the $\lambda_i$' seems a bit unappropriate to me.

Comment: @MooS I think you are right, yet the main argument remains exactly the same, namely: $\;T\;$ is diag. iff the sum of the geom. multiplicities of the eigenvalues is $\;n\;$  ... Thanks, editing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u_1, \dots,u_k$ be a basis of $\ker T$.
Let $v_1, \dots,v_m$ be eigenvectors for $\lambda_1, \dots,\lambda_m$ respectively.

Then $u_1, \dots,u_k, v_1, \dots,v_m$ are a basis for $V$ because eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent and $k+m=n$.

With respect to this basis, $T$ has a diagonal matrix: $diag(0,\dots,0,\lambda_1, \dots,\lambda_m)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta_0,\delta_1,\dots,\delta_m$ be the geometric multiplicities for the eigenvalues $0,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$. Then $\delta_0=\operatorname{nullity}(T)$ by definition. Let $\mu_0,\mu_1,\dots,\mu_m$ be the algebraic multiplicities. You know that $1\le\delta_i\le\mu_i$, for $i=0,1,\dots,m$.

In particular
$$
\delta_0+\delta_1+\dots+\delta_m\ge\delta_0+m
$$
and so
$$
n=\mu_0+\mu_1+\dots+\mu_n\ge
\delta_0+\delta_1+\dots+\delta_m\ge\delta_0+m=n
$$
the rightmost relation holding by assumption.

Can you show this forces $\delta_i=\mu_i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,m$?

By the way, what can you say about $\mu_i$ for $i=1,\dots,m$? (This is however not relevant for diagonalizability.)